# Removing unique_ptr´s from a Vector and using them as parameters for new Struct

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

The syntax of moving `std::unique_ptr<...>()` somewhat eludes me, and i can't find a clear answer(to me at least), as to how i should move the unique_ptr around.

I have some heap-allocated Nodes and would like to create new Nodes, which have two already existing Nodes as children. Which in turn are supposed to be inserted into the vector.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector> 

template <typename T>
struct Node{
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> left, right;
    Node(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> left, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> right){
          this->left = left;
          this->right = right;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void foo(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>> vec;
    //...
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + idx, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(new Node<T>(vec.at(vec.begin() + idx), vec.at(vec.begin() + idx + 1))));
}
```

I only get the error-meassage, that no matching function call was found.

```
expression.hpp:69:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node<int>, std::default_delete<Node<int> > >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Node<int>, std::default_delete<Node<int> > > > >::at(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::unique_ptr<Node<int>, std::default_delete<Node<int> > >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node<int>, std::default_delete<Node<int> > >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Node<int>, std::default_delete<Node<int> > > > > >)’
```

Cann somebody help, or has an idea, where i can look for the correct syntax, and which move/copy-function i should use?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message

Comment: From the semantical POV: Who should be the owner of that _unique instance_ after the operation?

Comment: The `std::vector`'s `at` member function takes an integer (technically a `size_t`) and not an iterator, so I think you can just use idx and idx + 1 directly in the calls to `at`.  It's not about syntax, but about the types.  I suspect that your error message says as much.

Comment: the owner should be the new Node @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @user463035818 did it, hope this is better

Comment: And you are happy with there being some equal-to-nullptr `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>`s in `vec`?

Comment: @Caleth Id rather not have them, to be fair ... only ptrs to Nodes should be in there ...

Comment: Not related to your problem, but instead of writing `std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>(new Node<T>(  /*left node*/, /*right node*/))` you should write `std::make_unique<Node<T>>( /*left node*/, /*right node*/ )`

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand ownership. You can have `vec` own all the nodes, or you can have each parent own it's `left` and `right`, or you can have both *share* ownership. Each of those will require some change to your existing code

Comment: I think i do understand it, just not how to apply it in C++. My wish is, that when foo gets called, two adjacent vectors in vec will be selected, and given to a new node, which in turn then occupies their space in vec(just one of the two obviously) ... after that, vec loses ownership of both and gains it over the new Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to merge two adjacent `Node`s in your vector. You will need to do this in multiple steps

```
template <typename T>
struct Node{
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> left, right;
    Node(std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> left, std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> right)
        : left(std::move(left)),
        right(std::move(right))
    {}
}
template <typename T>
void foo(){
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node<T>>> vec;
    //...

    // Identify first element
    auto first = vec.begin() + idx; 
    // and second element
    auto second = first + 1; 

    // make the merged node
    auto merged = std::make_unique<Node<T>>(std::move(*first), std::move(*second));

    // remove the now empty Node pointers - note that this relies on the adjacency of first and second
    auto pos = vec.erase(first, first + 2);

    // add the new node to the correct place
    vec.emplace(pos, std::move(merged));
}
```

Comment: +1 This will fix the problem of having empty (nullptr) nodes, which Clebo Sevic mentioned he'd rather not have in the vector.

Comment: How do i assign ```left``` and ```right``` to members of Node? = is a deleted function. Should i move again?

Comment: @CleboSevic The code in my answer moves when it needs to. In general member initializers are preferable to code in the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> vec.at(vec.begin() + idx)
> ```

Take a look at declaration of `at`. The argument type is `size_type` (an integer type). You're trying to pass an iterator.

Comment: Weirdly enough this has worked for me before ... but ill look into it; thx

Comment: okay, found where it worked for me. wasn't ```at``` but ``` erease ```